# How to forget Wifi Credentials stored in windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I have connected to a wifi connection as default as and when i login to my system.
I want to forget that connection credentials in windows 8.
Please suggest how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Manage Wireless Network Profiles](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/manage-wireless-network-profiles)

> Delete a profile within range:
>
> - Press and hold or right-click the network in the network list, and then tap or click **Forget this network.**
>
> Delete a profile that's out of range:
>
> - At the command prompt, type: **`netsh wlan delete profile name="ProfileName"`**